# How do I customize text color in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, customization

I'd like to customize the color of text in IPython, but am not sure how to do it.

I know that in Python, I can do this by ending `sys.ps1` and `sys.ps2` with an ANSI color code such as

```
sys.ps1=">>> \001\033[0m\033[34m\002"
```

But the corresponding approach, using `PromptManager.in_template`, does not work for IPython. For example

```
c = get_config()
c.PromptManager.in_template = 'In [{count}] : {color.Blue}'
```

has no effect on the color of text after the prompt.

Is there a way to change the color of text in IPython?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The prompt [explicitly sets](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/prompts.py#L390) the color of input to `colors.in_normal`.  If you want to change the input color, you have to change this color.

Unfortunately, customized color schemes are still on the todo list (should be pretty easy, just not a high priority).

A somewhat hackish example of what you seem to want, changing the color of input and/or output text in a config file:

```
from IPython.utils import coloransi
from IPython.core import prompts

termcolors = coloransi.TermColors() # the color table
# IPython's two color schemes:
dark = prompts.PColLinux.colors
light = prompts.PColLightBG.colors

# colors.in_normal affects input code
dark.in_normal = termcolors.Green
light.in_normal = termcolors.Blue
# colors.normal affects output
dark.normal = light.normal = termcolors.Red
```

This will set it so that the color of text matches the prompt, but you can of course choose whatever you want.

Comment: How would we do this in Windows? I might be missing something, but for my particular installation of iPython there is no object prompts.PColLinux

Comment: I'm using IPython 6.1.0 and there's also no `prompts.PColLinux` or `prompts.PColLinuxBG`. By the looks, this subsystem was rewritten in (or near) IPython 5 and I can't find anything equivalent in the latest versions, yet.

Comment: @minrk sorry for the dumb question, but where should we save that config.py?

Comment: @meowsqueak did you try my solution (which I only tested for ``5.5.0``) ?

Comment: @vaab I just tried your solution with IPython 6.2.1 (with python 3.6.2) - see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 41):

## Colorize and Syntax Style in IPython

First you have to create a ipython profile `~/.iphyton/ipython_config.py` in your home directory. **ipython_config.py**. The easiest way to do so is to run the following command:

```
ipython profile create
```

In case you are using `ipython3` start

```
ipython3 profile create
```

This will install a `profile_default` directory and some scripts in your `~/.ipython`; otherwise find this file on your machine and duplicate it in your **~/.ipython/profile_default/** directory.

Make a backup of this file with:

```
cp ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py{,_backup}
```

Open the `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` with an text editor of your choice and search for following settig and comment it out if you like it (delete the '#'):

- `c.InteractiveShell.color_info = True`
- `c.InteractiveShell.colors = 'Linux'`
- `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style = 'monokai'`
- `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlight_matching_brackets = True`

and so on. There are many usefull settings which are disabled by default; you have only to comment them out (deleting the `#' ).

**Style Files**

On Ubuntu/Debian  you have to install the [pygments](https://pygments.org/) package

```
sudo apt install python3-pygments
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install pygments
```

The style files can be found in following directory:

/path/to/your/python/**site-packages/pygments/styles/**, e.g.
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pygments/styles/monokai.py`

Alternatively, you can also list your installed styles with `pygmentize`:

```
pygmentize -L styles
```

Comment: It seems to ignore the style when choosing colors for the completer. Any idea on how to customize those?

Comment: This answer was helpful in concert with [https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/details.html](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/details.html).

Comment: For me it looks like it doesn't realize there are more then 16 colors (`ipython-5.1.0`), the blue color is particularly unreadable. `TERM=screen-256color`, Debian 9, `ncurses-base` and `ncurses-term` are installed. `vim` uses 256 colors. All those settings change nothing.

Answer (score 11):

**Warning:** This Answer is only compatible with `IPython` `5.5.0` and it does not seem to translate well with `IPython` `6+`. (thx @meowsqueak for the quick test !)

As of `IPython 5.5.0`, you can override any styling color thanks to the `ipython_config.py` in the targetted profile folder. (ie: `~/.ipython/profile_default` for `default` profile on a linux typical install).

IPython code is quite a mess related to colorizing and several methods are used for parsers, debuggers, interactive shell. Some part use `Pygments`, some other provide ANSI escape code that are limited to a 16 colors palette.

The solution is not pretty, but works. If there are any other prettier other way, please tell me in comment !.

Please note that my solution also includes the ability to use 256 colors or more for every part of IPython coloring, thanks to an extending of the default palette. There's an example of how to extend to 256 colors in the following code.

So here's how to do, with a list of all tokens that might be used:

```
##
## Basic color scheme that will be modified
##

colorLabel = 'Linux'
c.InteractiveShell.colors = colorLabel


from pygments.token import Token, Keyword, Name, Comment, String, Error, \
     Number, Operator, Generic, Whitespace

c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {

    ## Standard Pygments tokens (are all used by IPython ?)

    Whitespace:                "#bbbbbb",
    Comment:                   "italic #008800",
    Comment.Preproc:           "noitalic",
    Comment.Special:           "noitalic bold",

    Keyword:                   "bold #AA22FF",
    Keyword.Pseudo:            "nobold",
    Keyword.Type:              "bold #00BB00",

    Operator:                  "#666666",
    Operator.Word:             "bold #AA22FF",

    Name.Builtin:              "#fff", #""#AA22FF",
    Name.Function:             "#00A000",
    Name.Class:                "#0000FF",
    Name.Namespace:            "bold #0000FF",
    Name.Exception:            "bold #D2413A",
    Name.Variable:             "#B8860B",
    Name.Constant:             "#880000",
    Name.Label:                "#A0A000",
    Name.Entity:               "bold #999999",
    Name.Attribute:            "#BB4444",
    Name.Tag:                  "bold #008000",
    Name.Decorator:            "#AA22FF",

    String:                    "#BB4444",
    String.Doc:                "italic",
    String.Interpol:           "bold #BB6688",
    String.Escape:             "bold #BB6622",
    String.Regex:              "#BB6688",
    String.Symbol:             "#B8860B",
    String.Other:              "#008000",
    Number:                    "#666666",

    Generic.Heading:           "bold #000080",
    Generic.Subheading:        "bold #800080",
    Generic.Deleted:           "#A00000",
    Generic.Inserted:          "#00A000",
    Generic.Error:             "#FF0000",
    Generic.Emph:              "italic",
    Generic.Strong:            "bold",
    Generic.Prompt:            "bold #000080",
    Generic.Output:            "#888",
    Generic.Traceback:         "#04D",

    Error:                     "border:#ff0000",

    ## IPython

    Token.Number: '#ffffff',
    Token.Operator: 'noinherit',
    Token.String: '#8b8',
    Token.Name.Function: '#2080D0',
    Token.Name.Class: 'bold #2080D0',
    Token.Name.Namespace: 'bold #2080D0',
    Token.Prompt: '#ffffff bold',
    Token.PromptNum: '#888888 bold',
    Token.OutPrompt: '#008b8b bold',
    Token.OutPromptNum: '#006b6b bold',
}


from IPython.core import excolors, ultratb, debugger
from IPython.core.excolors import exception_colors as exception_colors_orig

##
## Add new color labels here before attributing them
##


from IPython.utils import coloransi

coloransi.color_templates = (
    # Dark colors

    ("Black"       , "0;30"),
    ("Red"         , "0;31"),
    ("Green"       , "0;32"),
    ("Brown"       , "0;33"),
    ("Blue"        , "0;34"),
    ("Purple"      , "0;35"),
    ("Cyan"        , "0;36"),
    ("LightGray"   , "0;37"),

    # Light colors
    ("DarkGray"    , "1;30"),
    ("LightRed"    , "1;31"),
    ("LightGreen"  , "1;32"),
    ("Yellow"      , "1;33"),
    ("LightBlue"   , "1;34"),
    ("LightPurple" , "1;35"),
    ("LightCyan"   , "1;36"),
    ("White"       , "1;37"),

    ## 256-colors

    ("Green108", "38;5;108"),
)

coloransi.make_color_table(coloransi.TermColors)
coloransi.make_color_table(coloransi.InputTermColors)

for name, value in coloransi.color_templates:
    setattr(coloransi.NoColors, name, '')


C = coloransi.TermColors
IC = coloransi.InputTermColors


def exception_colors():

    ex_colors = exception_colors_orig()

    ex_colors.add_scheme(coloransi.ColorScheme(
        colorLabel,

        # The color to be used for the top line
        topline=C.LightRed,

        # The colors to be used in the traceback
        filename=C.Green,
        lineno=C.DarkGray,
        name=C.Purple,
        vName=C.Cyan,
        val=C.White,
        em=C.LightCyan,

        # Emphasized colors for the last frame of the traceback
        normalEm=C.LightCyan,
        filenameEm=C.Green,
        linenoEm=C.Normal,
        nameEm=C.LightPurple,
        valEm=C.LightGreen,

        # Colors for printing the exception
        excName=C.Red,
        line=C.Yellow,
        caret=C.White,
        Normal=C.Normal
    ))
    return ex_colors

excolors.exception_colors = exception_colors
ultratb.exception_colors = exception_colors
debugger.exception_colors = exception_colors


##
## Parser color (source code colors)
##

from IPython.utils import PyColorize
import token
import tokenize

PyColorize.ANSICodeColors[colorLabel] = coloransi.ColorScheme(
    colorLabel, {
        'header'         : C.LightRed,
        token.NUMBER     : C.LightCyan,
        token.OP         : C.Normal,
        token.STRING     : C.Green108,
        tokenize.COMMENT : C.LightGray,
        token.NAME       : C.Normal,
        token.ERRORTOKEN : C.Red,

        PyColorize._KEYWORD         : C.White,
        PyColorize._TEXT            : C.Yellow,

        ## Keep IC here, you can use other colors

        'in_prompt'      : IC.Green,
        'in_number'      : IC.LightGreen,
        'in_prompt2'     : IC.Green,
        'in_normal'      : IC.Normal,  # color off (usu. Colors.Normal)

        'out_prompt'     : C.Red,
        'out_number'     : C.LightRed,

        'normal'         : C.Normal  # color off (usu. Colors.Normal)
})
```

Comment: I just tried your solution with IPython 6.2.1 (with python 3.6.2) within rxvt-unicode-256color and it seems to work partially - I get different colors to that with the default "Linux" scheme, but they are unusual. For example, the prompt is a very, very pale green with a pale blue-grey numerical part, yet keywords like `import` are bold magenta and `def` is bold blue. Do you have a screenshot for what it ought to look like?

Comment: @meowsqueak thanks for test. It is indeed strange that it actually changes colors but does not get the colors that were expected. I didn't share here a well crafted set of colors but only the Linux scheme with some changes to chosen colors, and ``import`` keyword should be bright white in this set. Well, I don't have the time now to check what's going on with IPython 6+, I've added a warning to the answer to clearly state that this works on IPython 5.5 but probably not on IPython 6+.

Answer (score 7):

The easy way to change colors in Ipython:

1. Open your IPython config file (`ipython_config.py`) , normally at `~/.ipython/profile_default/` or in `~/.ipython/profile_<your_usrname>/` (if you are using IPython profiles).
2. Find and uncomment (or change) setting `c.InteractiveShell.colors`
3. Change it to one of the color schemas available you can see them all listed here in the comments - `NoColor`, `Neutral`, `Linux`, or `LightBG`
4. Save config file and start IPython

**If you do not see the config file** - you can generate it quickly with the command:

`ipython profile create [profilename]`

It will generate config file with default settings and you can edit it then as needed.