# iPython - change color for double underscore (magic) attributes?

Tags: python, ipython

I updated iPython to:

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Mar 29 2019, 10:38:28) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

What I noticed is that double underscore attribute likes `__name__` have dark blue color. My terminal is black, so those attributes are ridiculously dark and hard to see (look at `A.__name__`):

[image]

Is there a way to modify colors on iPython?..

I found this question, but it seems with `7.4.0` iPython, given answers no longer work.

[How do I customize text color in IPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129278/how-do-i-customize-text-color-in-ipython)

Comment: Up-voted for the team, Ubuntu forever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking in your installation directory you will find a file called `ipython_config.py`. To install this file, simply use the following command:

```
ipython profile create
```

Otherwise find this file and copy it in your `~/.ipython/profile_default/` directory.

Before editing it, make a backup of this file with:

```
cp ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py \   
   ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py_backup
```

Open this file with your editor of choice, search for following setting and comment it out (delete the '#'):

```
#c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {}
```

you must have next code there:

```
## Override highlighting format for specific tokens

from pygments.token import Name
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {
   Name.Variable:    "#FF00FF"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Works on Python 3.6.8 // IPython 7.8.0

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It would be better for ipython to create `ipython_config.py` by default, cause at least in my case it was not created when I installed ipython.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the highlight color for any of the tokens defined in `pygments` - there's a list in the [pymgents documentation](http://pygments.org/docs/tokens/). The token you want to change is `Name.Function.Magic`. To do that, add the following to your `ipython_config.py` file (mine is in `~/.ipython/profile_default`):

```py
from pygments.token import Token

c.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {
        Token.Name.Function.Magic: '#FF00FF'
}
```

This will make magic functions highlight in magenta - your preferences may vary :)

Comment: In my case, I have `~/.ipython/profile_default` folder, but there is no `ipython_config.py`. Should I create one manually? Though, then I don't understand where this `c` variable come from you are using.

Comment: Yes, you can create the file. And the `c` is injected somehow - I don't know the details, but you don't need to instantiate it.

Comment: Well I created the file. But after opening ipython again. Nothing changed. I guess its ignoring that file.

Comment: This does work. I used the same version of Python and ipython. You just need to find the right place for the file. Try `ipython3 locate config` - that should tell you the directory you need to use.

Comment: It returns the same location I added `ipython_config.py` in. I tried creating that file directly in `~/.ipython`, then in `~/.ipython/profile_default`. But still nothing is changing. Maybe you need to explicitly specify path to `ipython_config.py` in some other place (which I don't know) or else it won't find it even if placed inside that directory?