# IPython tab completion menu colors are unreadable

Tags: ipython

Tab completion in IPython is practically unusable because the text is so difficult to read.

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

1. I didn't have an ipython configuration file so I created one:
   `ipython profile create`.
2. In my `ipython_config.py` I set `c.InteractiveShell.colors = 'NoColors'`. That made all my text white but the completion text didn't change.

[image]

I'm using the following software:

- [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) terminal: 0.14.1
- IPython: 7.5.0
- Pygments: 2.4.2
- prompt-toolkit: 2.0.9

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found **a** solution. It seems my terminal is using 24bit color and that must be interacting poorly with the defaults of IPython which defaults to 256 colors. You can test your terminal with this command:

```
printf "\x1b[38;2;255;100;0mTRUECOLOR\x1b[0m\n"
```

If you see 'TRUECOLOR', then your terminal supports true color.

I set that in my `ipython_config.py` file: `c.TerminalInteractiveShell.true_color = True`. Now the completion text is readable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer totally works. Just for future reference the file is: ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/49760043. You can create the config with defaults via `ipython profile create`. Or at least have a `c = get_config()` at the top of a manually created empty `ipython_config.py`.